# How to use getSelectionStart and getSelectionEnd of EditText when user touches EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to know by using which method I can get whether the user selecting text in edittext or not so I can use getSelectionStart and getSelectionEnd to perform my desire task.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if your `EditText` widget has been focused (usually when user touches it on the screen).

```
findViewById(R.id.editText1).setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
```

and then implement the listener (in this case within the same class)

```
public void onFocusChange(View arg0, boolean arg1) {
        switch(arg0.getId()){
        case R.id.editText1:
            if(arg1){
                // has focus
            }
            else{
                // doesn't
            }
            break;          
        }
    }
```