# How to use getSelectionStart and getSelectionEnd of TextViewwhen user touches?

Tags: android, parsing, text, textview

I want get text like phone number inside a textView by parcing, and i want use this getSelectionStart(), but it dosen't work?? can someone give me an example please.

Comment: You probably need to explain what you have tried, and post the code you use with getSelectionStart to understand why this not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a bad first answer because I mixed getselection with the new text api of 2.3.

You will find some answer in those thread :

[Android - get selection of text from EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163017/android-question-get-selection-of-text-from-edittext)

[How to use getSelectionStart and getSelectionEnd of EditText when user touches EditText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427380/how-to-use-getselectionstart-and-getselectionend-of-edittext-when-user-touches-ed)